# Is there a way to fill a listview in activity2 with info from a listview in activity1?

Tags: android-listview, args

Activity 1 sends the info I want to Activity 2:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                int position, long id)

        {

            // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);


            final int item_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(GamesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID));
            String item_cursus = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GamesDbAdapter.KEY_CURSUS));
            String item_onderdeel = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GamesDbAdapter.KEY_ONDERDEEL));
            String item_tijd = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GamesDbAdapter.KEY_TIJD));
            String item_game = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GamesDbAdapter.KEY_GAME));
            String item_web = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GamesDbAdapter.KEY_WEB));


            Intent intent = new Intent(actGames_FRONT_ListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.this, actGames_ALL_ListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("cursus", item_cursus);
            intent.putExtra("id", item_id);
            intent.putExtra("game", item_game);
            startActivity(intent);

            Toast done =

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item_game, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            done.show();

        }


    });
```

In Activity2 I want to display "game" in another listview, but setText doesn't work with Listview.

```
    game = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.game);
    Intent iin= getIntent();
    Bundle c = iin.getExtras();

    if(c!=null)
    {
        String item_game =(String) c.get("game");
       game.setText(item_game);
    }

 String game_list = getIntent().getExtras().getString("game");
```

This is the simplecursoradapter in activity2:

```
       private void displayListView() {


    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllCursus();

    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] cursus = new String[] {
            GamesDbAdapter.KEY_CURSUS,
    };


    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] {
              R.id.front,
    };

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    //as well as the layout information
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.games_row_front,
            cursor,
            cursus,
            to,
            0);



    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

And this is in my DBadapter:

```
      public Cursor fetchGames(){
    String[] args = {"********************" };
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, null,
            "cursus = ?" , args, KEY_GAME, null, null);


    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

When I replace the ********* with a static item from the database it works but I can't get it to work with the intent from the first activity. Is there a way to fill a listview with info from another listview in another activity?

Comment: in your second activity I do not see you pull the items out of the Intent.Extras

Comment: edited the question so you can see how I pulled the Extras. Hope it makes moree sence now.